# Finding words that start with a specific sign

Tags: excel

I have a few thousands rows in an Excel file with a line of text in each cell. In this line of text, there is sometimes a word that starts with the character "&". I would like to avoid using VBA.

If the words that start with "&" were always the same length, I would use "LEFT" or "RIGHT". What Excel function would you advise me to use to extract these words?

Other question: If I have two words that start with "&" in the same cell, is there any way to have two different functions, in two other cells, one looking for the first one starting from the beginning, the other one looking for the last one starting from the end?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you post your "other question" as a separate question.

Comment: I do not understand your second question. Do you want to clean only the first (or the last) word?

Comment: In addition to what has been provided, the MID function might help with your second part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question. Say in A1 there is your first string. Put in B1 this formula:

> =IF(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," &"," "),1)="&",MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," &"," "),2,10000),SUBSTITUTE(A1," &"," "))

Then drag down (copy formulas down) for cells A2, A3 ecc.. 
This take care of all the words that are preceded by a space and the first word in the cell. You have to look out of special case (interpunctions ecc..) as: "bla bla,&Word"

Answer (score 0):

`Left` and `Right` are still a great functions to use.

Say the word under inspection is K8.

You may obtain the first character with `=IF(LEFT(K8,1)="&",TRUE,FALSE)`.

You may obtain all the characters but the first by using `=RIGHT(K8,LEN(K8)-1)`.

Of course, you may replace the TRUE in the first statement with the RIGHT... of the second statement; I have broken them out for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

try the `INSTR` function to find the first occuance of &

```
instr(string,"&") 'returns the 1st occurance of &
```

then, if you need to find another occurance

```
instr(n,string,"&") 'returns the 1st occurance starting in position n - which can  be 1+ the result of the prior line
```

and `INSTRREV(string, "&")` will find the last occurance